# jQuery: Getting object value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

`console.log(this)` throws:

```
Object
    eles: Object
        container: x.fn.x.init[1]
        ele: x.fn.x.init[1]
        0: div.cropMain
        context: document
        length: 1
        prevObject: x.fn.x.init[1]
        selector: ".two .cropMain"
        __proto__: Object[0]
        img: x.fn.x.init[1]
```

How can I grab the selector value: ".two .cropMain"?

Comment: jquery object do have a property named `selector`. If you get undefined if for some other reason. Could you show your code?

Comment: @Chaplin couuld you post the entire function in which you  do console.log(this);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access it like this:

```
this.eles.selector
```